# CentOS error with iptables recent module

Tags: centos, iptables

This is the rule in iptables for stop sync_flood attacks:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp -m tcp --syn \
-m recent --name synflood --set

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp -m tcp --syn \
-m recent --name synflood --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 60 -j DROP
```

Error:

```
iptables: Unknown error 4294967295
```

I don't know what exactly to do, this ocurrs when insert the last rule "-m recent --name synflood --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 60 -j DROP"

Here the kernel version

```
2.6.18-274.12.1.el5PAE
```

Comment: Maybe there's some kernel module that you need to load first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search on Google for your error message lead to CentOS bug [3632](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=3632), which says:

> This is not a bug. You should increase maximum possible value for
>   `--hitcount` parameter (20 by default) by setting `ipt_recent` module option `ip_pkt_list_tot`.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> # cat /etc/modprobe.d/ipt.conf 
> options ipt_recent ip_pkt_list_tot=200
> ```
>
> Then reload module ipt_recent.

You're setting `hitcount` to `60`, so this sounds like it's probably the root of your problem.

Comment: Thanks I make the changes you posted, and sorry, but, how i can reload the module ipt_recent? Thanks. Restarted iptables (service iptables restart) but the problem persist.

Comment: You can reboot, if that's an option.  Otherwise, you should be able to `modprobe -r ipt_recent`, and then `modprobe ipt_recent`.  This might fail because the `recent` module is in use, so you can try preceding it by `service iptables stop` to drop all of your firewall rules first.  Make sure you save them!

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks, now the module was loaded correctly.